# Scala BigDecimal - loss of precision

Tags: scala, math, precision, bigdecimal, bigint

I need to do some precision calcs with Big Numbers and I have been trying with Scala `BigDecimal` but I have noted loss of precision.

As an example:

```
2^63 == 9223372036854775808
2^64 == 18446744073709551616
```

However when I do

```
println(BigDecimal.decimal(scala.math.pow(2, 63)).toBigIntExact())
println(BigDecimal.decimal(scala.math.pow(2, 64)).toBigIntExact())
```

I get

```
9223372036854776000 != 9223372036854775808
18446744073709552000 != 18446744073709551616
```

I don't know if I can get the exact `BigInt`.

Maybe I have to take other approach.

Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@ scala.math.pow(2, 63)
res0: Double = 9.223372036854776E18
```

You get `Double` on `math.pow`, and then you pass the result to `BigDecimal` - it means that you lost precision even before you started using `Big*` classes.

If you put numbers into `BigDecimal` when they are still small and haven't yet lost precision (and if you use the constructors correctly) then you'll get the expected result:

```
@ BigDecimal(2).pow(63).toBigInt
res4: BigInt = 9223372036854775808

@ BigDecimal(2).pow(64).toBigInt
res5: BigInt = 18446744073709551616

@ BigDecimal(2).pow(63).toBigIntExact
res6: Option[BigInt] = Some(9223372036854775808)

@ BigDecimal(2).pow(64).toBigIntExact
res7: Option[BigInt] = Some(18446744073709551616)
```